# method t4ToTable4 in object Scoped is deprecated: The sbt 0.10 style DSL is deprecated:

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to define a custom task in SBT. The code I have written is

```
lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGen = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map {(dir, cp, r, s) =>
     ....
}
```

I get a warning

```
warning: method t4ToTable4 in object Scoped is deprecated: The sbt 0.10 style DSL is deprecated: '(k1, k2) map { (x, y) => ... }' should now be '{ val x = k1.value; val y = k2.value }'.
See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html
lazy val slickCodeGen = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map {(dir, cp, r, s) =>
```

So I changed my code as per the suggestion in the warning

```
val sourceManagedValue = sourceManaged.value
```

And now i get an error

```
error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task or Def.setting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `.value` outside of when defining settings (e.g `foo := bar`) you need to wrap it in `Def.setting`/`Def.task`/`Def.inputTask` (or for more advanced cases `Def.settingDyn`/`Def.taskDyn`/`Def.inputTaskDyn`).

So for your case:

```
lazy val slickCodeGen = Def task {
  val dir = sourceManaged.value
  val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
  val r = (runner in Compile).value
  val s = streams.value
  ???
}
```